# Dbus GetIdletime not returning anything

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use the Rust `dbus` crate to get the current Gnome idle time. The following typed into a terminal returns the idle time in milliseconds:

*dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor /org/gnome/Mutter/IdleMonitor/Core org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor.GetIdletime*

I'm new to rust, but following through the dbus examples, after many tries and iterations, led me to the following code:

```
use dbus::{blocking::Connection, arg};

fn test_dbus(&self) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let c = Connection::new_session()?;

    let p = c.with_proxy("org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor", "/org/gnome/Mutter/IdleMonitor/Core", Duration::from_millis(5000));
    let (idle_time,): (u64,) = p.method_call("org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor", "GetIdletime", ())?;

    println!("Idle: {:?}", idle_time);

    Ok(())
}
```

That code does not print anything and seems to get stuck at the `method_call` line. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've just tested your code in a `main` function and it works fine. Maybe you are running it in a weird context, not in a regular desktop?

Comment: @rodrigo you're right, thank you. I just tried it in a test project and it works. The issue must be that I'm building this Gtk app using Gnome Builder, which I believe runs it in a virtual environment. I'm not sure how I will be able to get around this to test the program, but again, thank you for figuring this out.

Comment: Gnome Builder builds flatpaks, which are sandboxed, so I was able to make this code work by adding `"--socket=session-bus"` to the Manifest.

Comment: Since you solved the issue you could answer the question (and eventually accept it) to help future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in my question works, but only when compiling directly on the main system. I was using Gnome Builder, which compiles and runs everything in Flatpaks, which are sandboxed. This caused the code to fail. By adding the flag `"--socket=session-bus"` to the Flatpak Manifest, the program gained access to the session bus and I was able to capture the Gnome idle time using the code above.